# Mismatch in JVM Target Compatibility Between 'compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac' and 'kspDevDebugKotlin' in Gradle Build

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am working on an Android project, and encountering an issue with mismatched JVM target compatibility settings when trying to build the project. The error message is as follows:

'compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'kspDevDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

Here's the relevant section from my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all")
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }

    composeOptions { kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.2" }
}
```

I am using this ksp plugin:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp").version("1.9.0-1.0.13")
}
```

project level plugin:

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

I've tried setting the JVM target for Kotlin to 17 using jvmToolchain(17), but it seems like the 'kspDevDebugKotlin' task is still targeting Java 1.8. I have looked at Android Studio settings for kotlin compiler, and I have specifically set it to use 17.

How can I ensure that both tasks target the same Java version (Java 17 in this case)? Are there any additional configurations needed in the Gradle script to align these targets? Oddly enough, I have created a separate project, with the same libraries and build.gradle files, but with virtually empty source code, and the project compiles okay. I have checked gradle.properties for any differences, and there none.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error message disappeared after I updated a realm plugin version.